# how to assign functions to class fields in dart?

Tags: function, functional-programming, dart

I understand how to assign a function to a variable in dart but how about a class field? Im currently doing it like this:

```
class A{
    DivElement rootElement;
    void addClass(String newClass){
        rootElement.classes.add(newClass);
    }
}
```

but I was hoping dart would support doing it a little bit shorter, something like how you would with a regular variable:

```
class A{
    DivElement rootElement;
    addClass => rootElement.classes.add;
}
```

is there a syntax similar to the second code snippet in dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either call the method or make a getter that returns the actual function:

```dart
class A {
  DivElement rootElement;
  get addClass => rootElement.classes.add;
}
```

or:

```dart
class A {
  DivElement rootElement;
  addClass(newClass) => rootElement.classes.add(newClass);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion was almost right. Try to add `get` before `addClass` :

```dart
class A {
  DivElement rootElement;
  get addClass => rootElement.classes.add;
}
```